# VSTS code coverage on new code

Tags: .net, azure-devops, code-coverage

I'd like to add a policy for enforcing Code Coverage, something like: min 20% on all code, min 80% on new code.

Is there any way to achieve this for .Net project using VSTS? I think I can do it using SonarQube, but would like something out of the box instead.

Comment: Nice, down-vote without any comment, well played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn’t such feature available in VSTS.

On the other hand, sonarqube can be integrated with VSTS: [Analyzing with SonarQube Extension for VSTS/TFS](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS)